# Fast dot product for a very special case

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

Given a vector X of size L, where every scalar element of X is from a binary set {0,1}, it is to find a dot product z=dot(X,Y) if vector Y of size L consists of the integer-valued elements. I suggest, there must exist a very fast way to do it.

Let's say we have `L=4; X[L]={1, 0, 0, 1}; Y[L]={-4, 2, 1, 0}` and we have to find `z=X[0]*Y[0] + X[1]*Y[1] + X[2]*Y[2] + X[3]*Y[3]` (which in this case will give us `-4`).

It is obvious that X can be represented using binary digits, e.g. an integer type int32 for L=32. Then, all what we have to do is to find a dot product of this integer with an array of 32  integers. Do you have any idea or suggestions how to do it very fast?

Comment: how big and how sparse is your data?

Comment: “It is obvious that X can be represented using binary digits” – yes, but it’s not obvious that this will bring any performance improvements. Unless, of course, memory size matters. Is that the case?

Comment: Is your special case sufficiently special that you can rely on extensions? For instance with any kind of SIMD you might get more speed benefit from using vector operations than you get by packing X into a bitfield. You'd have to compare.

Comment: @Konrad: for a general algorithm memory size doesn't matter

Comment: Is L a fixed constant? If it is then it may have some implications for the optimal solution.... any information/constraints you can give will in general help in finding a faster solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This really would require profiling but an alternative you might want to consider:

```
int result=0;
int mask=1;
for ( int i = 0; i < L; i++ ){
    if ( X & mask ){
        result+=Y[i];
    }
    mask <<= 1;
}
```

Typically bit shifting and bitwise operations are faster than multiplication, however, the if statement might be slower than a multiplication, although with branch prediction and large L my guess is it might be faster. You would really have to profile it, though, to determine if it resulted in any speedup.

As has been pointed out in the comments below, unrolling the loop either manually or via a compiler flag (such as "-funroll-loops" on GCC) could also speed this up (eliding the loop condition).

**Edit**
In the comments below, the following good tweak has been proposed:

```
int result=0;
for ( int i = 0; i < L; i++ ){
    if ( X & 1 ){
        result+=Y[i];
    }
    X >>= 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for interesting solution, but X must not be an array - it should an integer.

Comment: @psihodelia, didn't understand the question. I've updated since.

Comment: alternativly one can replance mask[bit] with -bit

Comment: Ok, now your solution is much better! It is interesting however, whether it can be optimized further, e.g. whether if(X&(1<<i)) can be replaced or not?

Comment: @psihodelia, yes, it can be slightly optimized so that it only shifts by one. I've just made that change.

Comment: You could think about loop unrolling, if your L is 32 or so it may make sense to think about completely eliminating conditional instructions (in loop and if) to maximally exploit parallelism. At least on Intel/AMD CPUs the most expensive part of this code seems to be branching.

Comment: @Krystian, good point, but I'll let "-funroll-loops" take care of that.

Comment: I think performance will be better if you use the bitwise tricks as below to eliminate the conditional. Then when loop unrolling is applied you will probably get a completely branchless solution which I expect is optimal.

Comment: Don't use a variable mask. use (X and 1) and then shift X right by one bit each time. The conditional is OK on a modern intel or AMD because a good compiler (Intel or GCC) will make use of a conditional (non-branching) instruction which won't stall the pipeline.

Comment: I suppose, that on some architectures where MUL operation takes one CPU tick, result+=Y[i]*X&1; will be faster, because no branch is required.

Comment: Eliminate the conditional! `result += Y[i] & -(X&1);`

Comment: How about removing the if to do  : `result+=Y[i] * (X & 1);`

Comment: @SemicolonWarrier either way, it would require profiling... it's not obvious without it whether branch prediction or multiplication wins out. Using explicit branch prediction hints (like GCC's __builtin_expect, for example), might also be something to try. In all cases, this is something that requires profiling.

Answer (score 4):

Is a suggestion to look into SSE2 helpful? It has dot-product type operations already, plus you can trivially do 4 (or perhaps 8, I forget the register size) simple iterations of your naive loop in parallel.
SSE also has some simple logic-type operations so it may be able to do additions rather than multiplications without using any conditional operations... again you'd have to look at what ops are available.

Comment: No, thanks. SSE is a machine-specific implementation. I am looking for a general algorithm.

Comment: @psihodelia: You should definitely consider SSE; this problem would benefit enormously from stream processing.

Comment: @psihodelia: you make no sense. General algorithms can only be meaningfully compared in terms of asymptotic performance. If you want to compare performance you'll need to go machine specific and preferably benchmark in a realistic setting (code & data cache pressure, etc.)

@John: SSE4.1 would be even more helpful, it has widening instructions to expand the masks from bits. I threw together a quick example that does L=32 in 48 instructions, no branches, one cacheline of extra data: http://gist.github.com/400685

Comment: That's pretty cool. Although Even I'd argue SSE4 is not mainstream enough to target right now.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
int result=0;
for ( int i = 0; i < L; i++ ){
    result+=Y[i] & (~(((X>>i)&1)-1));
}
```

This avoids a conditional statement and uses bitwise operators to mask the scalar value with either zeros or ones.

Comment: Alternative for the bitwise operator that also works is:

result+=Y[i] & -((X>>i)&1);

Not sure which is faster....

Comment: Logically your second method contains one less op so "ought" to be faster

Comment: Yes I'd agree... though I've learnt over the years not to assume anything when it comes down to compiler optimisations and microprocessor quirks!

Comment: Practically they run the same speed, as I've tested.

Comment: Cool, thanks KennyTM (I didn't have a C compiler handy!). I've been working on the standard assumption that bitwise operations are basically free on modern processors for quite a while :-)

Answer (score 3):

Since size explicitly *doesn’t* matter, I think the following is probably the most efficient general-purpose code:

```
int result = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    result += Y[i] & -X[i];
```

Bit-encoding `X` just doesn’t bring anything to the table (even if the loop may potentially terminate earlier as @Mathieu correctly noted). But omitting the `if` inside the loop *does*.

Of course, loop unrolling can speed this up drastically, as others have noted.

Comment: I think, on some architectures, Y[i]*X[i] takes less instructions than AND and negation.

Comment: @psihodelia:  Less instructions does not necessarily mean less runtime (especially on a CISC architecture).

Comment: @psihodelia: That’s irrelevant. You can be pretty sure that negation + bitwise and will *always* be faster than multiplication.

Comment: For a general algorithm it does matter how many operations are involved. On RISC architecture one operation should be faster than two.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is identical to, but slightly faster (by my test), than Micheal Aaron's:

```
long Lev=1;
long Result=0
for (int i=0;i<L;i++) {
  if (X & Lev)
     Result+=Y[i];
  Lev*=2;
}
```

I thought there was a numerical way to rapidly establish the next set bit in a word which should improve performance if your X data is very sparse but currently cannot find said numerical formulation currently.

Comment: MA has modded his solution to include this optimisation. He has my upvote

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a number of responses with bit trickery (to avoid branching) but none got the loop right imho :/

Optimizing `@Goz` answer:

```
int result=0;
for (int i = 0, x = X; x > 0; ++i, x>>= 1 )
{
   result += Y[i] & -(int)(x & 1);
}
```

Advantages:

- no need to do `i` bit-shifting operations each time (`X>>i`)
- the loop stops sooner if `X` contains 0 in higher bits

Now, I do wonder if it runs faster, especially since the premature stop of the for loop might not be as easy for loop unrolling (compared to a compile-time constant).

Comment: Nice. How about also incrementing i to skip the zeros in X at the beginning of the loop?

It's extra code but it avoids memory accesses so it ought to be a net win.....

Comment: Been thinking about this: since we've gone to the effort to eliminate branches with bitwise operations it probably doesn't make sense to add them back in with variable length loops, at least for the case where L is a small fixed number. If the ones and zeros are random 50% then you only save on average one memory access on each side of the vector.

Comment: +1 Nice on the early out.  It doesn't, however, provide a win if there is a 1 in the top bit however as you still do just as many right shifts.  It may, however, be easier to pipeline for the compiler.

Comment: Can you please explain the cast to `int`? Isn’t that quite unnecessary? (`x & 1` **is** an `int`.)

Comment: @Rudolph: I don't know, I just copied this bit from `Goz`. @mikera/Goz: I am not sure about the termination condition either as I am afraid it could screw up with the loop unrolling, however bit-shifting by 1 in each loop does seem faster :)

Answer (score 2):

How about combining a shifting loop with a small lookup table?

```
    int result=0;

    for ( int x=X; x!=0; x>>=4 ){
        switch (x&15) {
            case 0: break;
            case 1: result+=Y[0]; break;
            case 2: result+=Y[1]; break;
            case 3: result+=Y[0]+Y[1]; break;
            case 4: result+=Y[2]; break;
            case 5: result+=Y[0]+Y[2]; break;
            case 6: result+=Y[1]+Y[2]; break;
            case 7: result+=Y[0]+Y[1]+Y[2]; break;
            case 8: result+=Y[3]; break;
            case 9: result+=Y[0]+Y[3]; break;
            case 10: result+=Y[1]+Y[3]; break;
            case 11: result+=Y[0]+Y[1]+Y[3]; break;
            case 12: result+=Y[2]+Y[3]; break;
            case 13: result+=Y[0]+Y[2]+Y[3]; break;
            case 14: result+=Y[1]+Y[2]+Y[3]; break;
            case 15: result+=Y[0]+Y[1]+Y[2]+Y[3]; break;
        }
        Y+=4;
    }
```

The performance of this will depend on how good the compiler is at optimising the switch statement, but in my experience they are pretty good at that nowadays....

Comment: I like your solution better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no general answer to this question. You need to profile your code under all the different targets. Performance will depend on compiler optimizations such as loop unwinding and SIMD instructions that are available on most modern CPUs (x86, PPC, ARM all have their own implementations).

Answer (score 1):

```
result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < L ; i++)
    if(X[i]!=0)
      result += Y[i];
```

Comment: How is this superior to `if (X[i] == 1)`? And why isn’t it a good idea?

Comment: It is in fact inferior to `if(X[i] == 1)`.
It is not a good idea because having anything except `bool` in conditional statement is considered bad. :)

Comment: @TheMachineCharmer: So then why not write `X[i] == 1` in your answer? From an efficiency point of view, it’s the same (!) and that would be a good answer, even though it uses a conditional which has been avoided completely by other answers.

Comment: Typically comparisons with zero are faster than comparisons with other values as most machines have a jump-if-zero, jump-if-not-zero, and other jump statements based on zero. Comparing with other values typically implies a subtraction followed by a comparison with zero.

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan: That is great idea and answers the first question of Konrad Rudalf and clarifies my doubts. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

For ***small*** L, you can use a switch statement instead of a loop. For example, if L = 8, you could have:

```
int dot8(unsigned int X, const int Y[])
{
    switch (X)
    {
       case 0: return 0;
       case 1: return Y[0];
       case 2: return Y[1];
       case 3: return Y[0]+Y[1];
       // ...
       case 255: return Y[0]+Y[1]+Y[2]+Y[3]+Y[4]+Y[5]+Y[6]+Y[7];
    }
    assert(0 && "X too big");
}
```

And if L = 32, you can write a dot32() function which calls dot8() ***four*** times, inlined if possible. (If your compiler refuses to inline dot8(), you could rewrite dot8() as a macro to force inlining.) **Added**:

```
int dot32(unsigned int X, const int Y[])
{
    return dot8(X >> 0  & 255, Y + 0)  +
           dot8(X >> 8  & 255, Y + 8)  +
           dot8(X >> 16 & 255, Y + 16) +
           dot8(X >> 24 & 255, Y + 24);
}
```

This solution, as mikera points out, may have an instruction cache cost; if so, using a ***dot4***() function might help.

**Further update**: This can be combined with mikera's solution:

```
static int dot4(unsigned int X, const int Y[])
{
    switch (X)
    {
        case 0: return 0;
        case 1: return Y[0];
        case 2: return Y[1];
        case 3: return Y[0]+Y[1];
        //...
        case 15: return Y[0]+Y[1]+Y[2]+Y[3];
    }
}
```

Looking at the resulting assembler code with the -S -O3 options with **gcc** 4.3.4 on CYGWIN, I'm slightly surprised to see that this is automatically inlined within dot32(), with ***eight*** 16-entry jump-tables.

But adding __attribute__((__noinline__)) seems to produce nicer-looking assembler.

Another variation is to use fall-throughs in the switch statement, but **gcc** adds jmp instructions, and it doesn't look any faster.

***Edit--Completely new answer:*** After thinking about the 100 cycle penalty mentioned by Ants Aasma, and the other answers, the above is likely not optimal. Instead, you could ***manually*** unroll the loop as in:

```
int dot(unsigned int X, const int Y[])
{
    return (Y[0] & -!!(X & 1<<0)) +
           (Y[1] & -!!(X & 1<<1)) +
           (Y[2] & -!!(X & 1<<2)) +
           (Y[3] & -!!(X & 1<<3)) +
           //...
           (Y[31] & -!!(X & 1<<31));
}
```

This, on my machine, generates 32 x 5 = 160 fast instructions. A smart compiler could conceivably unroll the other suggested answers to give the same result.

But I'm still double-checking.

Comment: I like this! My only question would be whether the instruction cache cost outweighs the obvious advantage in terms of number of operations?

Comment: @mikera: **Time it.** It's the only way to tell. Alas, it's quite possible that the massively unrolled version won't be faster due to it being harder for the processor to hold all that code in its ICache (and do other useful work too).

Comment: The larger problem is that this has 8 indirect jumps. Thats more than 100 cycles of penalty right there, not including the time to actually add stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite likely that the time spent to load `X` and `Y` from main memory will dominate. If this is the case for your CPU architecture, the algorithm is faster when loading less. This means that storing `X` as a bitmask and expanding it into L1 cache will speed up the algorithm as a whole.

Another relevant question is whether your compiler will generate optimal loads for `Y`. This is higly CPU and compiler dependent. But in general, it helps if the compiler can see precsiely which values are needed when. You could manually unroll the loop. However, if L is a contant, leave it to the compiler:

```
template<int I> inline void calcZ(int (&X)[L], int(&Y)[L], int &Z) {
  Z += X[I] * Y[I]; // Essentially free, as it operates in parallel with loads.
  calcZ<I-1>(X,Y,Z);
}
template< > inline void calcZ<0>(int (&X)[L], int(&Y)[L], int &Z) {
  Z += X[0] * Y[0];
}
inline int calcZ(int (&X)[L], int(&Y)[L]) {
    int Z = 0;
    calcZ<L-1>(X,Y,Z);
    return Z;
}
```

(Konrad Rudolph questioned this in a comment, wondering about memory *use*. That's not the real bottleneck in modern computer architectures, bandwidth between memory and CPU is. This answer is almost irrelevant if Y is somehow already in cache. )

Comment: N.B. I don’t question that less memory transfer potentially increases performance; I questioned whether this was “obvious”. Of course, caching is a very important factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your bit vector as a sequence of ints where each int packs a couple of coefficients as bits. Then, the component-wise multiplication is equivalent to bit-and. With this you simply need to count the number of set bits which could be done like this:

```
inline int count(uint32_t x) {
    // see link
}

int dot(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    return count(a & b);
}
```

For a bit hack to count the set bits see http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel

Edit: Sorry I just realized only one of the vectors contains elements of {0,1} and the other one doesn't. This answer only applies to the case where both vectors are limited to coefficients from the set of {0,1}.

Answer (score 0):

Well you want all bits to get past if its a 1 and none if its a 0.  So you want to somehow turn 1 into -1 (ie 0xffffffff) and 0 stays the same.  Thats just -X .... so you do ...

```
Y & (-X)
```

for each element ... job done?

Edit2: To give a code example you can do something like this and avoid the branch:

```
int result=0;
for ( int i = 0; i < L; i++ )
{
   result+=Y[i] & -(int)((X >> i) & 1);
}
```

Of course you'd be best off keeping the 1s and 0s in an array of ints and therefore avoiding the shifts.

Edit: Its also worth noting that if the values in Y are 16-bits in size then you can do 2 of these and operations per operation (4 if you have 64-bit registers).  It does mean negating the X values 1 by 1 into a larger integer, though.

ie YVals =  -4, 3 in 16-bit = 0xFFFC, 0x3 ... put into 1 32-bit and you get 0xFFFC0003.  If you have 1, 0 as the X vals then you form a bit mask of 0xFFFF0000 and the 2 together and you've got 2 results in 1 bitwise-and op.

Another edit:

IF you want the code on how to do the 2nd method something *like* this should work (Though it takes advantage of unspecified behaviour so it may not work on every compiler .. works on every compiler I've come across though).

```
union int1632
{
     int32_t i32;
     int16_t i16[2];
};

int result=0;
for ( int i = 0; i < (L & ~0x1); i += 2 )
{
    int3264 y3264;
    y3264.i16[0] = Y[i + 0];
    y3264.i16[1] = Y[i + 1];

    int3264 x3264;
    x3264.i16[0] = -(int16_t)((X >> (i + 0)) & 1);
    x3264.i16[1] = -(int16_t)((X >> (i + 1)) & 1);

    int3264 res3264;
    res3264.i32  = y3264.i32 & x3264.i32;

    result += res3264.i16[0] + res3264.i16[1];    
}

if ( i < L )
    result+=Y[i] & -(int)((X >> i) & 1);
```

Hopefully the compiler will optimise out the assigns (Off the top of my head i'm not sure but the idea could be re-worked so that they definitely are) and give you a small speed up in that you now only need to do 1 bitwise-and instead of 2.  The speed up would be minor though ...

Comment: I have checked your solution , but it gives me totally wrong answers. One has to find a dot product of a binary word with an array of integers.

Comment: Well you DO have to add up the results earlier.  You also need to promote the values in the Y vector to integers for it to work.

Comment: Does a code example help?  You'd still have to profile both ways because it IS plausible the branch is cheaper ... My method is, however, constant time.

Comment: @Goz - looked at the worked example in the text; your algorithm cannot be made to do this.

Comment: @Goz - yea, thanks! Your algorithm indeed is very good. I have checked it, it gives good results.

Comment: @Elemental: Do you mean the idea of doing 2, or more, at once?  IT requires modifications to me algorithm above but it IS doable ...

Comment: Updated slightly to reduce the X calculation by 1 op.

Comment: Updated again to show a possible way to reduce the number of bitwise-ands by half for a small speed up.

Comment: I wonder if you could optimize the code by shifting in the loop so as to only need 1 bit-shift by iteration (instead of `i`), I've posted a separate answer though because I don't know if this would not mess up with the loop unrolling...

Answer (score 0):

Represente `X` using linked list of the places where `x[i] = 1`.
To find required sum you need `O(N)` operations where `N` is size of your list.

Comment: This is a good idea if X is sparse AND X is relatively static. Obviously the fastest implementation would be some kind of contiguous array as opposed to the linked list suggested here.

Comment: @Elemental you mean sparse, relatively static, and large.

Comment: Yeah and the questioner implies that the size of X is less than 32 which definitely isn't large.